# Can't print report header in every page in classic report

Tags: dynamics-nav

how to print report header in every page in Classic report in Nav 2009. I try to see section property (PrintOnEveryPage = yes) . Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Do you have any details such as the structure of the report? A screenshot of data items and list of section types? All this information makes it easier to answer :)

Comment: Actually there are for header section of report.. I need to set them all ..problem solved...

Comment: Yes, same with Place in Bottom (Worst named property ever :P) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only suggestions I can offer with the current details provided is that you ensure PrintOnEveryPage is set to yes (Shift + F4 while selecting a Header section).

Apart from that, ensure that your have your header on a DataItem such as PageLoop vs another DataItem that may not be run on every page. PageLoop Header examples are found through all sorts of NAV repotrs e.g. 206 Sales Invoice.